# Need Help Installing TensorFlow Docker Image

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I'm trying to create a Tensorflow Image Classifier using this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfNvhPx5Px8&t=204s) and I am stuck on the second step of the tutorial.

I tried running the command `docker run -it gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel` but when I do it, my terminal returns with the following error message:

> Unable to find image 'gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel'
>   locally docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for
>   gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel not found. See 'docker run
>   --help'.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Your command is good. Either the `tensorflow` image is not present in that repository or the `latest-devel` tag is incorrect. Checking.

Comment: Ah, it appears to be moved to docker.io so you can just use `tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel` (drop the GCR prefix of `gcr.io/`): `docker run -it tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel`

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to download and run tensorflow:

```
docker run -it tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel
```

It will download the image from tensorflow. Thanks to DazWilkin.

Comment: How does your answer an improvement of the comment of @DazWilkin?

Comment: @commonsense It is in the place where it is supposed to be. The answer section.